# geotiff conversion to coordinate system with gdal

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

I would like to get the coordinates X Y Z from a geotiff file.

I am using the gdal translate for the conversion.

Which output format is the more adequate for containing a 3 numpay array X Y Z ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?  It sounds like you have a DTM.  In which case you can just open the raster as an array in Numpy.  this will give you an array of Z values.  The x,y are then derived by the column/row in relation to the raster origin and resolution.  No conversion is necessary (i.e. unless you are doing something unusual, you only need a 2-dimensional array).

Comment: I have used a gdal script before , I have managed to read X Y Z , for a a large geotiff it takes a lot of a time. I am trying to do it using the gdal translate tool

Answer (score 1):

To convert GeoTIFF to XYZ you can simply use:

**gdal_translate -of XYZ geotiff.tif geotiffas.xyz**

From python for all tif files in the directory:

```
def main(my_path):
  import os
  import subprocess

  # What/Where to load and save
  source_directory = my_path
  target_directory = my_path
  # Create dir for processed files
  if not os.path.exists(target_directory):
    os.makedirs(target_directory)
  # Find all tif
  file_names = [files for files in os.listdir(source_directory) if files.endswith(".tif")]

  for file_name in file_names:

      # Convert tif to XYZ
      gdal_command = "gdal_translate -of XYZ \"" + source_directory + "\\" + file_name + "\" \"" + target_directory + "\\" + file_name[:-3] + "xyz" + "\""
      subprocess.call(gdal_command)

  print("All done!")

# Call itself automatically only if run as stand alone  
if __name__ == "__main__":
  import os
  my_path = os.getcwd()
  main(my_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

HERE is what I have managed to do

```
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

width = ds.RasterXSize
height = ds.RasterYSize

gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
minX = gt[0]
minY = gt[3] + width*gt[4] + height*gt[5] 
maxX = gt[0] + width*gt[1] + height*gt[2]
maxY = gt[3] 

print "the domain :" , "[" ,minX,";",maxX,"]","[", minY,";",maxY ,"]"

#showing a 2D image of the topo
# plt.imshow(elevation, cmap='gist_earth',extent=[minX, maxX, minY, maxY])
# plt.show()


# elevation 2D numpy array
elevation = band.ReadAsArray()

a = gt[1]
b = gt[2]
d = gt[4]
e = gt[5]

def pixelcoord(x, y):
  """Returns coordinates X Y from pixel"""
  xp = a * x + b * y + minX
  yp = d * x + e * y + minY
  return xp, yp


#"creating X Y Z file..."
f = open("coordinates.dat", "wb")
for i in range(height):
  for j in range(width):
     pp= pixelcoord(i,j)
     print >> f, pp[0] , pp[1] , elevation[i][j]
```

Comment: Warning: `pixelcoord` gives the pixel corner coordinate (usually upper left). To get the centre, you need to apply a half-pixel transformation.

Comment: Is there any reason to write this script when you can simply use gdal_translate -of XYZ geotiff.tif geotiffas.xyz ?